# Windows Mobile Hopper Test Tool, FocusApp

Tags: c++, testing, windows-mobile

Hi recently I finished my WM6 Pro.6.1 application and happily learned that to put it into marketplace, it has to pass some tests.

-Application Verifier
-Microsoft Hopper Test Tool for Windows Mobile 6.0, 6.1, and 6.5

I use VS 2008 and windows mobile 6.1 and I couldnt run none of these tests, Hopeer tool has a FocusApp c++ application which I must build and run before testing, but its a VS 2005 project and I couldnt run it on VS 200..and without it I can't test anything.

any ideas how can I build that for VS2008?

Comment: Why couldn't you build it? What specific errors did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tips for this process in this blog post:
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wmdev/archive/2010/02/18/windows-marketplace-for-mobile-certification-testing-hopper-and-multiple-screen-support.aspx

Try these first. If they don't work post more information on what specific problems you're having.